# How do I find out what snap-in was just installed?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have several Windows Server 2008 R2 instances that I work with.  Today I log in to one of these boxes, and among the other IS "on log-in" scripts that normally run, a pop-up appeared that said, "Installing Snap-in."

What do I have to do to find out what snap-in was just installed?

Comment: was this your first login to that box? could be adding snap-ins to a new profile.

Comment: Nope; I've logged into the box multiple times before.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that may help is to go into the registry at this location (assuming your speaking about MMC):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns
```

From here you can see the Name and Description of each snap in.  You then can verify against another computer or your own knowledge of what you expect to see.